# Cypress tests running on all machines using circleci parallelism

Tags: cypress, circleci

I am using cypress and circleci for my current application. I am able to setup 4 parallel machines on circleci. The issue is I see all tests running on each machine separately instead of distributing the tests across the machines. I followed the article https://www.mariedrake.com/post/run-tests-in-parallel-using-circleci Below is the config.yml file. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        parallelism: 4
        steps:
              // all previous steps
        command: |
              mkdir cypress/tmp
              mv $(circleci tests glob "cypress/tests/**/*.spec.js" | circleci tests split --split- by=timings) cypress/tmp || true
              npx cypress run
```

All tests pass on all 4 machines but there is no use as I am not able to save time using the parallelism feature.

Comment: I remember reading about this on the gitter cypress group chat. I can vaguely recall something about Cypress Dashboard paid version handling how to best distribute all the tests instead of all tests running on all machines. I can't find the conversation though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the space between '--split-' and 'by' and try again please? Also split by time looks into the previous runs to get the time taken for the spec files to run and then balance it accordingly. So suggest sending -store_test_results in the commands with a path like below,

-store_test_results
path: test-results